# does `sizeof(std::max_align_t)` have actual meaning?

Tags: c++

C++ introduces `std::max_align_t` as

> std::max_align_t is a trivial standard-layout type whose alignment requirement is at least as strict (as large) as that of every scalar type.
> (from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/max_align_t)

but without saying about the size of it. (I also checked c++ draft).

But both gcc and clang implement it with size=32 and align=16 for x86-64 or arm64. ([godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/edd9jra94))

And in this [cppreference example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size#Example), `2 * sizeof(std::max_align_t)` is used as a fall back of `std::hardware_destructive_interference_size`(Indeed, both gcc and clang do not implement it).

```cpp
#ifdef __cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size
    using std::hardware_constructive_interference_size;
    using std::hardware_destructive_interference_size;
#else
    // 64 bytes on x86-64 │ L1_CACHE_BYTES │ L1_CACHE_SHIFT │ __cacheline_aligned │ ...
    constexpr std::size_t hardware_constructive_interference_size
        = 2 * sizeof(std::max_align_t);
    constexpr std::size_t hardware_destructive_interference_size
        = 2 * sizeof(std::max_align_t);
#endif
```

So does `sizeof(std::max_align_t)` have actual meaning from c++ stardard or gcc/clang implementation? Or why gcc and clang implement it with size greater than alignment?

In addition, clang on Apple M1 Macs implements `std::max_align_t` with size=8 and align=8 when targeting arm64, but size=16 and align=16 when targeting x86_64.

###### Edit:

In [gcc/ginclude/stddef.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/gcc/ginclude/stddef.h) `std::max_align_t` is dedfined as

```cpp
/* Type whose alignment is supported in every context and is at least
   as great as that of any standard type not using alignment
   specifiers.  */
typedef struct {
  long long __max_align_ll __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof__(long long))));
  long double __max_align_ld __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof__(long double))));
  /* _Float128 is defined as a basic type, so max_align_t must be
     sufficiently aligned for it.  This code must work in C++, so we
     use __float128 here; that is only available on some
     architectures, but only on i386 is extra alignment needed for
     __float128.  */
#ifdef __i386__
  __float128 __max_align_f128 __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof(__float128))));
#endif
} max_align_t;
```

but did not explain why the member `long long __max_align_ll` is needed.

I guess a possible reason is that gcc wants to make sure
alignment of `max_align_t` is at least as strict (as large) as both `long long` and `long double`. But that example on cppreference abused it.

Comment: "*in this cppreference example*" That example has been changed, apparently in response to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every type has a size, and that size must be at least its alignment (and will be a multiple of its alignment, just like any type). Therefore, `sizeof(max_align_t)` will be no smaller than `alignof(max_align_t)`. Exactly what this size will be beyond that is not specified and ultimately means nothing.

The cppreference page was incorrect about the relationship between `hardware_destructive_interference_size` and `max_align_t`. [The standard states](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/hardware.interference#1) only that it shall be at least `alignof(max_align_t)` bytes. That is, the smallest destructive interference is at least the alignment for any scalar type.

Comment: *will be an even multiple of its alignment, just like any type*  This is incorrect. sizeof(char) == alignof(char) == 1, sizeof(char[3]) == 3 * alignof(char[3]) == 3.

Comment: *Even* multiple meaning no remainder, not that the multiple is an even number (2, 4, 6, etc...).

Comment: @DM Thanks and sorry, i'm not a native speaker and not good at English. Is there reference for *even multiple meaning no remainder* ? Both https://math.answers.com/Q/What_is_an_even_multiple and https://translate.google.com say that an even multiple means the multiple is an even number, they might be wrong though.

Comment: Ahh, yeah this might be a case where a native speaker subconsciously makes the connection to "[evenly divided](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divide%20evenly)". Nine can be evenly divided by three even though they are both odd and the result of the division is odd. I agree that the phrase is more idiomatic than mathematically rigorous.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you.